# Google API Picker: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-api, polymer, picker

I've trying to write a Polymer Element for a google file picker, but I keep getting the same error `google is not defined`, when it comes to creating the picker ...

`google` was found one time, but I refactored my code, because it didn't work as it was and it wasn't well programmed. But now I don't know why it doesn't work and I don't know how it found `google`!

```
<paper-button id="pick">Pick file</paper-button>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'google-file-picker',

    properties: {
        apiKey: {
            type: String,
            observer: 'pickerInit'
        },
        apiLoaded: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
        }
    },

    attached: function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js';
        script.onload = this.onApiLoad();
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    },

    pickerInit: function() {
        var oAuth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
        if(this.apiLoaded && (this.apiKey !== null || this.apiKey !== undefined)) {
            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                .setOAuthToken(oAuth2)
                .setDeveloperKey(this.apiKey)
                .setCallback(this.onSelect)
                .build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
        }
    },

    onApiLoad: function() {
        this.apiLoaded = true;
        this.pickerInit();
    },

    onSelect: function(file) {
        this.fire('file-selected', {file: file});
    }
});
</script>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, I imported the Google Js API and then I want to refer to the `google` Object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded the main Google JS library (`gapi`) but you didn't load the actual picker part of the library.

In your `onApiLoad` method you need something like this before `google.picker` will be available:

```
gapi.load(
    'picker',
    {'callback': this.pickerInit.bind(this)}
);
```